# @Google-cloud/storage suddenly throwing weird exception after working for a long time

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

**Context:**

I have an API endpoint which serves .stl files stored in a public Google Cloud Storage bucket. Until sometime this week, it was working fine. I can step all the way through my code with the debugger. The NPM module in question is not even referenced in my project. I've tried using the exact code on Googles documentation for download and get the same exception: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/downloadFile.js

**What I've tried**

`npm rebuild @google-cloud/storage` and different ways of using the same Google npm package.

**Questions:**

1.) Shouldn't the catch, catch the exception to prevent the crash?

2.) Anyone have any ideas on a workaround?

**File:**
https://storage.cloud.google.com/fancy_induction_ui/1inX1in.stl

**Code:**

```
  getFile: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const fileName = req.param('file');
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName + '');
      const storage = new Storage();
      let file = await storage.bucket('fancy_induction_ui').file(fileName).createReadStream();
      file.pipe(res);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({message: 'Something is wrong!', err: e.message});
    }
  }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
path/to/code/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:317
  var isBuf = !state.objectMode && _isUint8Array(chunk);
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectMode' of undefined
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (path/to/code/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:317:22)
    at PassThrough.ondata (_stream_readable.js:714:22)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at PassThrough.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at PassThrough.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:512:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:989:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:970:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Comment: The catch clause would prevent the crash if the issue was coming from the server. This looks like an issue in the readable-stream for Node.js. See [Fixing a TypeError bug when state is undefined](https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/pull/419/commits/873bb553b056bbcb1a64ffa5814877721a2a9704). Perhaps upgrading to the latest release might help. Feel free to raise your issue in Node.js GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/issues).

Comment: @matt-gardner  did you fix the issue?  I have the same problem...

Comment: As above, i've got the same issue with mssql which uses tedious. Anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Im having the exact issue, but only in my test environment.. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I believe the correct fix was to hard code an old version of readable-stream in package.lock as @ValeraChecha suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion bug in different versions readable-stream in deep dependencies.
I have added

`readable-stream: "3.6.0"`

to my package.lock and that's fixed for me this issue.

Comment: What about with multiple dependencies using readble stream? I have some using different versions and on an npm install it just re-uses 3.4.0 for example.